# Firefox 5.0 jquery/post timeout problem

Tags: jquery, firefox, post

I have a strange timeout error, but I'm not sure how to debug it.

I have a client using Firefox 5.0 on XP, accessing a website I am developing, where the POST requests for a dynamic page timeout after about 30 seconds.  As in, they work for about 30 seconds, and then stop... until the page is reloaded.

I suspect it's something with the client's firewall, but the site works fine when they use IE7 (although IE7 has other problems and isn't a solution).  When I run from a similar configuration in my development environment I can't reproduce the timeout problem.

The backend is a django site running on Apache through mod_wsgi (but I don't think that matters), and I use POST requests with jQuery to dynamically update a page, specifically:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/app/portal',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {parameter: 'value'},
  success: function(json){
    //...
  },
  error: function(xhr, testStatus, error) {
    //...
  }
});
```

It was a fresh install of firefox (and had the problem before and after I installed the firebug plugin).

Is there anything I can check?  Is there something I'm missing?  Is it possible to determine if it's a firewall issue or some other IT problem?

Further details:

1. There was no record in apache's access log.
2. The communication was over SSL.
3. Non ajax calls (ie, links to other pages on the site) worked okay.

Clearing the cache also has no effect.

I am not sure about the client's network configuration - could there be proxy or something else that would be causing such a timeout?

Comment: May be an error in the script call by Ajax, can you post it ?

Comment: Thanks - the ajax call is the same as above (using jQuery's $.ajax), except the parameters are different - and it works fine under normal circumstances.  It is only when I am onsite with the client that I have this issue on their computers.  (Both my and their computers are running xp with firefox 5).

Comment: How often are you making these POST AJAX calls?  Are you waiting for a completed success before firing off the next request, or are you just invoking your ajax method directly via setInterval?

Comment: could you tell one thing, how many simultaneous ajax requests are you making on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest installing [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and watching exactly what goes out and what come in.

Comment: Problem went away with Firefox 6.0.  Fiddler helped to get a better picture of what was going on - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine this being a firewall issue unless you're using a different port (but that doesn't appear to be the case)
Just a couple of basic pointers I guess:

1. Check your access log (is the request coming in at all)
2. Ask you client to use the web inspector in FireFox to see what's happening to the request
3. Make sure this is not some pesky caching problem (have them clear their cache)
4. What happens if they make a normal (non-ajax) request to that URL

Comment: Thanks.  1 - There is no record in apache's access log.  2 - Looking at firebug when I was onsite I saw the POST request with no response (although I forget what the status was).  3 - Didn't check the cache... will investigate.  4 - reloading the page worked normally, as did visiting another page on the site.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message when you get timeout? According to your description about SSL, working IE, working in your computer and so on, it might be SSL certificate issue too. Would you check if their firefox has proper certificate for the site? (Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Encryption)

Comment: Thanks for the idea - it looks like the proper certificate is there though.